# EER Diagramming - Are unlabeled specialization branches overlapping or disjoint by default?

Tags: constraint, erd, eer

My understanding is when documenting specialization constraints (i.e. Disjointness Constraint) in EER diagrams you label the subclass branches as "o" for overlapping and "d" for disjoint. I can't find any references that describe what the default "disjointness" is when it is unmarked. For example, in the EER diagram below the path to the manager subclass is unmarked, does that mean it is overlapping or disjoint with the other two disjoint branches? If the answer is yes, then this implies an employee can be a Manager and a Secretary, which is fine but I am missing the point of the "Engineering_Manager" entity if that is the case.

**Primary Questions:**

- Are unlabeled specialization branches overlapping or disjoint by default?
- When there are multiple branches how are the branches treated? (i.e. do the distict branches overlap with eachother)

[image]